# Parse JSON in Swift 4 from Youtube and Alamofire - Nested JSON

Tags: swift, youtube, youtube-api, swift4, youtube-data-api

I'm still learning parsing JSON in Swift 4 and the latest example I am working on is proving to be a little complex, although probably simple in appearance.

I access the date through....

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                print(JSON)
                let value = JSON["rows"]
                print(value!)
            }
```

However I want to access just the value inside the (( )).

```
{
    columnHeaders =     (
                {
            columnType = METRIC;
            dataType = INTEGER;
            name = estimatedMinutesWatched;
        }
    );
    kind = "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable";
    rows =     (
                (
            20
        )
    );
}
```

I am trying to access the value 20 in this case. When I put into a JSON validator, I get an error of "key doesn't exist".

But as well, the value 20 is double nested in the JSON.

This is an extract from the Youtube Analytics API.

Comment: The data you have show is in the plist-like format used in `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, not a JSON text. You should better show the original JSON as text, as well as your code to get that data.

Comment: @OOPer I see that it is a dictionary, however the difficulty I face at the minute is to access the value as it is wrapped in (()). I can access rows with....`if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                print(JSON)
                let value = JSON["rows"]
                print(value!)
            }`

Comment: **_however the difficulty I face at the minute is to access the value as it is wrapped in (())_** Many developers are not accustomed to plist-like notations, so _show the original JSON as text_ would help you to get better answers sooner. You might get answers, just that it may take a longer time.

Comment: Edit your question to show the original JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your content is a dictionary with a key "rows" that contains an array of arrays of `Int`s.

Simulating your data:

```
let rows = ["rows": [[20]]] as NSDictionary

if let row = rows["rows"],
    let rowAsArray = row as? [[Int]] {
    print(row)
    print(rowAsArray[0][0])
}
```

The first print statement outputs:

```
(
        (
        20
    )
)
```

That looks like your output format.